# Plot images as axis labels in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I am plotting a 7x7 pixel 'image' in MATLAB, using the `imagesc` command:

```
imagesc(conf_matrix, [0 1]);
```

This represents a [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), between seven different objects. I have a thumbnail picture of each of the seven objects that I would like to use as the axes tick labels. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Knowing the width/height of the axes, as well as the spacing of tick labels and the axes limits, you can calculate the position of tick marks. Then you add 14 more axes in the image to plot the thumbnails. It's possible, but not easy.

Comment: Just a thought: scaling pixel brightness this way means that the confusion cells with the least an most counts will always appear as black and white.  It may be useful to consider scaling some other way, since the spread of these values is also informative.  For isntance, if the confusion matrix counts are [900 40; 60 1000], it means something very different than were they [510 480; 490 520], although the relative ordering of the cells is the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know an *easy* way. The axes properties `XtickLabel` which determines the labels, can only be strings.

If you want a not-so-easy way, you could do something in the spirit of the following non-complete (in the sense of a non-complete solution) code, creating one label:

```
h = imagesc(rand(7,7));
axh = gca;
figh = gcf;
xticks = get(gca,'xtick');
yticks = get(gca,'ytick');
set(gca,'XTickLabel','');
set(gca,'YTickLabel','');
pos = get(axh,'position'); % position of current axes in parent figure

pic = imread('coins.png');
x = pos(1);
y = pos(2);
dlta = (pos(3)-pos(1)) / length(xticks); % square size in units of parant figure

% create image label
lblAx = axes('parent',figh,'position',[x+dlta/4,y-dlta/2,dlta/2,dlta/2]);
imagesc(pic,'parent',lblAx)
axis(lblAx,'off')
```

One problem is that the label will have the same colormap of the original image.

Comment: Thanks, I can mould this into what I want it to do. It's a shame about the colormap. In the meantime, I've hacked together a dirty solution using subplots, which I'll post as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

@Itmar Katz gives a solution very close to what I want to do, which I've marked as 'accepted'. In the meantime, I made this dirty solution using subplots, which I've given here for completeness. It only works up to a certain size input matrix though, and only displays well when the figure is square.

```
conf_mat = randn(5);
A = imread('peppers.png');
tick_images = {A, A, A, A, A};

n = length(conf_mat) + 1;

% plotting axis labels at left and top
for i = 1:(n-1)
    subplot(n, n, i + 1); 
    imshow(tick_images{i});
    subplot(n, n, i * n + 1);
    imshow(tick_images{i});
end

% generating logical array for where the confusion matrix should be
idx = 1:(n*n);
idx(1:n) = 0;
idx(mod(idx, n)==1) = 0;

% plotting the confusion matrix
subplot(n, n, find(idx~=0));
imshow(conf_mat);
axis image
colormap(gray)
```

[image]