# Add node numbers/get node locations from MATLAB's treeplot

Tags: matlab, tree, plot

I have been working with MATLAB's [treeplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/treeplot.html) function, but it seems to provide surprisingly little plotting functionality and/or extendibility.

I am plotting a tree like so:

```
tree = [0  1  2  2  2  2  2  1  8  8  1  11  11  1  14];
treeplot(tree)
```

Giving:
[image]

What I would like to do is add annotations or labels to specific nodes. A good starter would be to add the node numbers to each node, as in the example from the help file:

[image]

As they state, though:

> These indices are shown only for the point of illustrating the example; they are not part of the treeplot output.

Is there a way to get the locations of the plotted nodes, or at the very least to plot the node numbers? I couldn't find any FEX submissions with more advanced tree plots.

Ultimately, I'd like to plot small pictures at the nodes (using methods from [answers to a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850002/plot-images-as-axis-labels-in-matlab/4851060#4851060)).

Comment: Are these pictures generally missing or filtered out at my site.

Comment: I don't know... I've got them both showing here. The first one I made and uploaded, the second was originally from the MathWorks site (but both i believe are now hosted on `i.imgur`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the position of the nodes, use [treelayout](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/treelayout.html)

```
[x,y]=treelayout(tree);
```

The vectors x and y give you the positions, which you can then use to plot images at the nodes.

Answer (score 9):

This should help you make a labeled tree:
(You supply the 'treeVec'.)

```
treeplot(treeVec);
count = size(treeVec,2);
[x,y] = treelayout(treeVec);
x = x';
y = y';
name1 = cellstr(num2str((1:count)'));
text(x(:,1), y(:,1), name1, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom','HorizontalAlignment','right')
title({'Level Lines'},'FontSize',12,'FontName','Times New Roman');
```

With your sample input, this gives
[image]