# Matlab plot a complicated structure

Tags: matlab

I implemented ID3 decision tree with Matlab and I used struct() to store the decision tree.

Basically the tree structure looks like this:

```
root: Attr1
left: [1x1 struct]
right: [1x1 struct]
```

Yeah, the tree structure is constructed in a recursive manner.

Is there any quick workaround so that I can plot my tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (and someone can correct me if I'm wrong) that there is no built-in way to flatten a recursive struct. One possible way to plot your tree is to use `treeplot`, which requires your data to be in a particular format. You could achieve this in the following manner:

```
function [nodes,attr] = flatten_struct(dtree,level,nodes,attr)
% Flattens the decision tree struct into a format usable by treeplot
if isempty(dtree)
    return;
end
if nargin==1
    level=0;
    nodes=[];
    attr={}; 
end
nodes = [nodes,level];
attr = [attr,dtree.root];
[nodes,attr] = flatten_struct(dtree.right,level+1,nodes,attr);
[nodes,attr] = flatten_struct(dtree.left,level+1,nodes,attr);
```

You would call this code with `[nodes,attr] = flatten_struct(tree)`, and then you can plot the tree using `treeplot(nodes)`. You should be able to add labels using the method outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065051/add-node-numbers-get-node-locations-from-matlabs-treeplot) answer to a different question. Something like:

```
[nodes,attr] = flatten_struct(tree);
treeplot(nodes);
[x,y] = treelayout(nodes);
for k=1:length(nodes)
    text(x(k),y(k),attr(k));
end
```

though you'd probably have to fiddle with the `x` and `y` values so that they don't overlap the tree nodes.